# How to get the source port being used by java.net.HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java

I am using the `java.net.HttpURlConnection` or `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` objects for connecting to http/https servers. My tests failed at some point because apparently all they had used up all the available ports on my local machine. These are persistent http connections and therefore should be reused.

I am trying a few things to fix this. But to check whether my fix works, I need to make sure that the same port on the source machine is getting used in subsequent instances of `HttpURlConnection` or `HttpsURLConnection`. How can I get the source port being used by `java.net.HttpURLConnection`?

Comment: You used up all 65535 ports? O.o

Comment: Apparently yes. I'm dealing with object stores that can store hundreds of thousands of objects. Interacting with these objects can easily lead to port exhaustion if there are no persistent connections.

Comment: That sounds like bad design. When you release and close a socket properly it becomes reusable.

Comment: After closing a TCP socket, it goes into the TIME_WAIT state. By default, it remains in this state for 60 seconds and only then is it available for reuse.
I agree there can workarounds for this. But I'm trying to understand why persistent http connections are not getting used here. One way to verify that the connection is persistent would be to make sure that several different HttpUrlConnection objects use the same underlying port.

Comment: Even then, I have a hard time believing 65k connections are being gone through in 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any methods that allows same local port bind in HttpURlConnection or get local port number being used for binding. There is some methods in Java's Socket class that allows you to bind same local port ( constructor method and bind() I think ) though... Check PlainConnectionSocketFactory in Apache httpclient 4.x than Socket if you want to go this way since those HttpClient has more handy methods.

Answer (score -1):

Either you specify the port as a part of [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) you supply to your HTTP connection or defaultone  is used.

Either way, **your** URL object has this information and you can inquire about it with its [`getPort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPort()) method.

Comment: That's the destination port. I'm trying to find out the port used on the source side.